# Problema ao marcar todos os checkbox

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Como devo proceder para marcar os input's checkbox? Está apenas desmarcando.

Seguem os códigos para auxílio:

```
HTML

<div class="col-md-11">
<div style="text-align: right;" class="checkbox">
<label><input type="checkbox" ng-click="marcarDesmarcarTodos('checkParticipantes')" id="ckeckAll" name="checkAll" />Marcar/Desmarcar Todos</label>
</div>
</div>

<input type="checkbox" name="checkParticipantes" ng-click="ckeckMarcarDesmarcarTodos()" ng-model="participante.selecionados[pessoa.ID_PESSOA_EVENTO]" />
```

JavaScript - AngularJS

```
$scope.ckeckMarcarDesmarcarTodos = function () {
        if( $('#ckeckAll').is(':checked')) {
            $('#ckeckAll').prop("checked", false);
        }else {
            $('#checkAll').prop("checked", true);
        }
    };        

$scope.selectedAll = false;
$scope.marcarDesmarcarTodos = function ()
{
    $scope.selectedAll = !$scope.selectedAll;
    if ($scope.selectedAll) {
        $scope.participante.selecionados = {};
        angular.forEach($scope.participante, function (item) {
            $scope.participante.selecionados[item.idPessoaEvento] = $scope.selectedAll;
        });
    } else {
        $scope.participante.selecionados = {};
    }
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Salve o valor atual em uma varíavel:

- `var isChecked = $('#ckeckAll').is(':checked');`

E "inverta" o valor de `checked`

- `$('#ckeckAll').prop('checked', !isChecked)`;

Se for checado, irá alterar para não checado e vice versa.

```
$scope.ckeckMarcarDesmarcarTodos = function () {
  var isChecked = $('#ckeckAll').is(':checked');
  $('#ckeckAll').prop('checked', !isChecked);
};
```

Answer (score 4):

Faça assim:

```
$scope.ckeckMarcarDesmarcarTodos = function () { 
     if( $('#ckeckAll').is(':checked') ) {
           $('#ckeckAll').prop( "checked", false );
     } else {
           $('#ckeckAll').prop( "checked", true);
     }
};
```

Faltava apenas um else para marcar os checkbox, tambem troquei o removeAttr por prop, que é mais indicado.

Comment: Wagner, ainda continua do mesmo jeito.

Comment: Wagner, infelizmente não funcionou !

Comment: Como está os checkbox que serão marcados/desmarcados? coloca o código deles ai pra vermos.

Comment: Wagner, editei os códigos novamente abaixo da pergunta, conforme vc solicitou.

Comment: Coloca um id nos checkbox assim id="checkParticipantes", ai no script altere para $('#checkParticipantes').prop( "checked", false ); e  $('#checkParticipantes').prop( "checked", true);

Answer (score 4):

Uma solução puramente Angular (sem jQuery):

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('myController', function($scope){
  $scope.selected = {};

  $scope.items = ['Item 1','Item 2','Item 3','Item 4']; 

  $scope.checkAll = function(){
    angular.forEach($scope.items, function(i){
      $scope.selected[i] = true;
    });
  };
  
  $scope.checkNone = function(){
    $scope.selected = {};
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller='myController'>
    <div ng-repeat="i in items">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selected[i]" ng-false-value="" />{{i}}
    </div>
<br/>
    <a href="#" ng-click="checkAll()">Marcar Todos</a><br/>
    <a href="#" ng-click="checkNone()">Desmarcar Todos</a>

    <pre>{{selected|json}}</pre>
  </div>
</div>
```

A utilização de código jQuery em conjunto com Angular é geralmente não recomendada porque a execução ocorre ao largo do ciclo *digest* do Angular, o que pode quebrar o *2-way binding*.

Comment: Concordo OnoSendai! Sempre melhor utilizar apenas Angular (ou outro framework), assim como quando se utiliza jQuery, procurar usar ao máximo todos os recursos e não utilizar JS puro.